# Run sql query with sqlalchemy that contains temporary table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

My problem is the following :
I'm trying to run an sql query that create multiple temporary tables, to get one result.

I have an sql query in a .sql file and i want to get the result in an pandas DataFrame.

My code is the following :

Sql :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #temp
SELECT
    TOP 100 NAME
    INTO #temp
FROM
    DB_CLI

SELECT * FROM #temp
```

Python :

```
from sqlalchemy.engine import URL, create_engine
import pandas as pd

def sql_exec(requete):
    connection_string = "DRIVER={SQL Server};\
        SERVER=SERVER\
        DATABASE=DATABASE"
    connection_url = URL.create(
        "mssql+pyodbc",
        query={"odbc_connect": connection_string}
    )

    engine = create_engine(connection_url)

    with engine.begin() as conn:
        with open(requete, encoding='utf-8') as r1:
            resultat = pd.read_sql(r1.read(), conn)
    
    return resultat

sql_exec('path_to_sql_query/sql_query.sql')
```

And i'm getting this error :

> ResourceClosedError: This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically.

My question is the following : is there a way to execute query that contains temporary table ?
My sql database runs under sql server 2022.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Try adding `SET NOCOUNT ON;` to the beginning of your SQL code block.

Comment: Thanks you @GordThompson for your solution !
This works for the demo example that i gave in my message, but not on the real (and more complex) query that I want to run..
The query runs fine with this code add on sql server btw.
But this is a good start to investigate !